# Use function from .then method of Promise outside its scope

Tags: javascript, promise, paint, web-performance

I have a file called **paintTiming.js**, which uses the [Paint Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformancePaintTiming) for finding out Web Performance paramters such as First Paint and First Contextual Paint. The file contents are shown below:

```
var FP, FCP, obj = [];

function parent() {
    if ("PerformanceObserver" in window) {
        let observerPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // access the PerformanceObserver interface
            let observer = new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
                resolve(list);
            });

            observer.observe({
                entryTypes: ["paint"]
            });
        }).then((list) => {
            // Find out First Paint and First Contextual Paint
            FP = list.getEntries()[0].startTime;
            FCP = list.getEntries()[1].startTime;
            // Store in array
            obj[0] = FP;
            obj[1] = FCP;
            element = "The paint times are: <br> First Paint : " + FP + "ms, <br> First Contentful Paint : " + FCP + "ms";
            // show values on web page
            document.getElementsByTagName('p')[1].innerHTML = element;
        }).then(() => {
            // check if array is created, and is functioning
            console.log(obj[0]);
        }).then(() => {
            // create function
            function abc() {
                return {
                    a: obj[0],
                    b: obj[1]
                };
            };
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.warn(error);
        });
    }
};
```

As you can see, a function abc() *should* be created when the promise is resolved.

My question : How do I use this function outside the promise?

For example, consider the sample below (used in a HTML file):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="paintTiming.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // should return object containing FP and FCP values    
    console.log(abc());
</script>
```

The console shows that the function is not defined. If the JS code is inline, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not able to use the function if this is declared inside `.then`. Because this function `abc` is private to the callback function passed to `.then` & .then will only execute with the ajax.

Alternatively you can define this function outside the `Promise` and call this function inside the `.then` callback. Also need to `bind` the context using `this`

Comment: I get the first part, but I'm sorry I didn't get what you mean by the second part. How exactly would I define the function outside the promise? How would I bind the context using 'this'? Pardon me for the noobish questions as I am very new to JS.

Comment: If that's too broad, any direction you could point me towards would be appreciated.

Comment: Never mind, didn't Google before commenting. Now know enough to proceed. Appreciate the help.